# I2C OLED will not turn on or display

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, i2c, led

I have started using the Arduino language instead of the pyFirmata version. I am using an Arduino UNO. I have run into the same problem, and that is that the OLED won't work. I've tried 2 different OLEDs, one from UCTRONICS and one from HiLetGo. They are both I2C 128x64 OLEDs, and the UCTRONICS one is yellow and blue while the HiLetGo one is all white. I've tried 2 different codes, one that I made and one example from the ssd1306 library. There are no errors, the OLEDs just don't light up. The board is alco connected to 4 touch sensors I am using for the same project but they have nothing wrong with them (yet). I have troubleshooted for a while now, and I have been able to pinpoint where the error is (probably) located. This is my code: (even though the ssd1306 I2C 128x64 example also doesn't work.) I also do not want suggestions that require extra hardware that I don't have, like an RTC (even though it is not related to this that was the only example I could come up with) This is my code: (even though the ssd1306 I2C 128x64 example also doesn't work.)

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define OLED_RESET 4
#define sw 128
#define sh 64
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(sw, sh, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x78);
  display.cp437(true);
  pinMode(A4, OUTPUT);


}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(A4, HIGH);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.println("test");
  Serial.println("test");
  digitalWrite(A4, LOW);

}
```

Like always, I only have 1 week to fix this so **help would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your I2C address setting appears wrong. Arduino's Wire library ([doc](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/wire)) uses 7 bit address. The last bit is read/write bit and `Wire` automatically takes care of it. So, you want to chop off the least significant bit and set the address to `0x3C` instead of `0x78`.

[Adafruit_SSD1306](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306) library actually uses `0x3C` as a default address. See the declaration and notes for `begin()` in .h and .cpp files.

For more info, I suggest looking at [SSD1306 data sheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1306.pdf). Here is the I2C data format. See how slave address is formatted.

[image]

Comment: I think I can try that but on the back of the OLED it says 0x78 so I put that there. I can still try changing that though.

Comment: The last bit is read/write bit. Arduino automatically takes care of it. If you read UCTRONICS's data sheet, it says "I2C slave address is set with 8bit address 0x78 (7 bit address is 0x3C) by default."

Comment: @KentaroOkuda that image from datasheet is just confusing (as the whole datasheet) and not correct ... the `Co` does not work for multibyte transfer (making it useless on I2C) also the LCD does not send ACK signal after first BYTE... The control BYTE is sended only once not every other BYTE ...

Comment: @Spektre I've never used SSD1306 and cannot tell if the datasheet is wrong. I only intended to show how the slave address is formatted. But are you sure that it doesn't ACK after receiving a byte? I guess the master still generates a 9th clock pulse. How would that work? Please educate me. I'm curious.

Comment: @KentaroOkuda Yes I am sure (I extensively measured the stuff) ... at least the ones I have at disposal they ACK just once per packet (after the slave address) and then stop (but still receiving data)... making impossible to use real HW I2C implementations. The Arduino I2C lib is ignoring subsequent ACKs so it works but HW does not and stops transmition as I2C specification requires.

Comment: Solved about a year ago

Comment: I dont know why i am commenting

Comment: Hello hello hello

Comment: Hi hi hi hi hi hi

Comment: Why am i doing this

Comment: Just anser my newest question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these displays can be very annoying. I have experienced it myself.

First, go to the website of the supplier and see if they suggest any specific libraries to use. Some of the main issues I encountered are:

- The supply voltage of the screen is not the standard 5V you expected but higher or lower. If it's lower or you supplied 5V to a 3.3V power in you might even have damaged or broke the display.
- You switched the SDA/SDL wires up, forgot to connect some wires or have a faulty ground. Does the backlight work?
- The library uses the wrong clockspeed
- The I2C address the display is listening on differs from the one used in the library (this is the most common one for me)

Comment: I don’t know if I have a backlight because it is an OLED. Maybe you’re talking about something else?

Comment: Also i used 5.0 volts first but I changed it to 3.3 but I know that you are saying that the 5.0v may have broke the OLED.

Comment: I’m new to this arduino stuff so I don’t know what you mean by clockspeed. Is it like the baud rate?

Comment: On the back of both OLEDs it has an I2C a dress of 0x78 if I’m not mistaken.

Comment: SSD1306 LCDs I have work with 5V and 3.3V without problems (even according to datasheets its not a problem). My top clock speed is 150/2 KHz  but that might be limited by the wiring, SW jitter  and stuff around and not LCD itself. Too slow speed makes also problems. Usual adress is 0x3C but you should probe for the address (autodetect)

Answer (score 0):

It's not every time the fault of hardware, check the program as well. Load example test program and try again. https://iotforgeeks.com/i2c-oled-display-not-working/ helped me to resolve the same issue.